# Check_MK/Nagios script to monitor multipath count

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, nagios, check-mk

i'm noob in bash.

I want to create check so if 1 path is dead i want to get warning message,more than 1 path down-critical, no dead path-all is OK

i would use this command and it's output:

```
powermt display dev=all 

CHECK_DEGRADED=/usr/local/bin/sudo /sbin/powermt display | grep dead| wc -l
 if [ $CHECK_DEGRADED -eq 1 ]; then

status=1
statustxt=WARNING

 else if [ $CHECK_DEGRADED -gt 1 ];  then

status=2
statustxt=CRITICAL


else

status=0
statustxt=OK

 fi
```

output should be something like: Path is in $statustxt state

Answer (score 0):

First of all Welcome to Stack Overflow.

1. declare an array of path
2. scan on all of them
3. check if the path exist
4. if exist increment a counter
5. then check the counter for exit status

Something like that should be fine:

```
deadPath=0
 declare -a pathArray=(/usr/local/bin/sudo /sbin/powermt display)
 for i in "${pathArray[@]}"
 do
   if [ -d "$i" ]; then
      # Will enter here if path exists
      echo "Path $i Exists"
   else
    deadPath=$[$deadPath+1] 
   fi
done
if (( deadPath > 1 )); then
  echo "Critical"
  exit 2
elif (( deadPath == 1 )); then
  echo "Warning"
  exit 1
else 
  echo "OK"
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Daniele i'll give it a try !1

Comment: For Nagios nrpe you will need to exit each condition with the status, 0 for OK, 1 for problem and 2 for critical

Comment: Yes @dragan.vucanovic, just replace the echo with the exit status. 
Approved review.

Comment: No, the echo will be needed to return a message to the Nagios console. It will need the exit status AND the echo (only one line of text)

Comment: and i would like at the end to add final output so i added something like this:        echo "Path is in $statustxt state" but then check_mk complains "Exception in check plugin "local",invalid line in agent section <<local>> OK"

Comment: @dragan.vucanovic You mean at the end of the script?

Comment: Exit command terminates the script, so you can't add something after the fi part. You can modifiy the echo statement before the exit value

Comment: i followed this example https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_localchecks.html

Comment: It's a little bit differet, in my script i just exit the result value.  In your example it printout at the end of the script the exit status and other info. 
You can do both way

Comment: Dragan, you will be able to echo variables back in the echo statement but you will need to make sure that any problematic characters are escaped correctly.

Comment: @dragan.vucanovic Please provide a feedback on my answer if is all complete. Thanks.